# Extracting words within HTML tages in Python/Pandas

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have HTML text I scraped which needs to be formatted into a table. I would like to extract everything with the bold tag: `<b></b>` I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
html='<b>HR</b>Shohei Ohtani<br><b>2B</b>Mike Trout(2)/<br><b>SF</b>Billy Bob'
```

Thus far, I've tried to put it into a list and then into a dataframe:

```
html_list=html.split('br')
html_df=pd.DataFrame(html_list,columns=['content'])
```

This yields:

```
print(html_df)
                     content
0    <b>HR</b>Shohei Ohtani<
1  ><b>2B</b>Mike Trout(2)/<
2        ><b>SF</b>Billy Bob
```

I want this:

```
print(html_df)
                     content var
0    <b>HR</b>Shohei Ohtani< HR
1  ><b>2B</b>Mike Trout(2)/< 2B
2        ><b>SF</b>Billy Bob SF
```

I tried using beautiful soup and .findall, to no avail. I'm open to different approaches, including reversing some of my steps.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='<b>HR</b>Shohei Ohtani<br><b>2B</b>Mike Trout(2)/<br><b>SF</b>Billy Bob'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
b_tags = soup.find_all('b')

for b_tag in b_tags:
   print(b_tag.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

Just use one line of code as follows:

```
html_df['var'] = html_df['content'].str.extract(r'<b>.*?(.*)</b>')
```

#### Result

[image]